# Transferring data between phone and raspberry pi

Tags: android, nfc

I was wondering if anyone had any information of how one would transfer data between a android app and a raspberry pi.  Specifically how I would transfer a array of information through the use of nfc. Thank you.

Comment: What information you exactly want to transfer?

Comment: In terms of type of information i want it to be in a json array, and for the sake of a example lets say that it's employee information(name, home address, etc)

Comment: Let me try to clear up some confusion with this(in order to do so let me give a example) I am trying to build a way for employees to check in and out of there shifts at work easier by just holding there phone to a scanner, I also want there to be app where the employee can go on and track there pay,hours,etc.  However in order to do this there will have to be a transfer of data between the phone and a sensor(or in this case a raspberry pi). Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have NFC support on your RPi, there are various ways to exchange messages with an Android device (which of them could work depend on what NFC front-end you chose):

1. Implement the peer-to-peer protocol stack and the SNEP protocol to
   exchange an NDEF message through Android Beam.
2. Implement a card emulator that emulates an NFC tag that can be
   accessed by an Android device that is in reader/writer mode.